# Flink docker compose - custom library

Tags: java, docker-compose, cluster-computing, apache-flink, classpath

I am trying to setup a Flink session cluster using docker-compose. I would like to have a custom library loaded in Flink as this library contains code that is used by all of my jobs. The way I do this by creating a custom docker image like the following:

```
FROM flink:1.10.0
WORKDIR /opt/flink/lib

RUN mkdir /opt/flink/usrlib
RUN chown flink:flink /opt/flink/usrlib

ADD --chown=flink:flink ./myLibrary.jar /opt/flink/lib/myLibary.jar
```

The job/task managers start successfully. When I submit a job using the Web UI my job runs correctly with one exception:

In my library I have a flink map operator (called DeserialisationMapper) which consumes JSON messages from Kafka and creates custom Java Objects based on a tag in the message. For example if the message is

```
{"objectType": "Address", "street": "Street 1"}
```

my DeserialisationMapper produces a Java POJO, instance of class Address having its field called "street" set to "Street 1". I do that using Java reflection. The custom Java classes for the POJOs **are only available in the job** itself (not the library).  When I execute my program in my Eclipse (my custom library is provided as a Maven dependency) everything works fine. The DeserialisationMapper is able to locate the custom Java classes located in the job project. When I export a "fat" jar for the job, that is a jar that includes all the dependencies of the job (e.g., myLibrary.jar) and deploy it to a flink cluster it works fine too. But, when I try to put my library in the flink cluster (using the custom image shown above) and exclude it from the job jar I get a ClassNotFoundException prompting that the specific class (e.g., Address) cannot be located, although the path to that class looks correct (e.g., org.eclipse.myJob.datatypes.Address) - I confirmed that the class is located in the job jar in the correct location. NB.: my job can actually access methods in the myLibrary.jar as for example the Kafka consumer is created in a method in myLibrary.jar which is called by my job).

Why is this happening? Shouldn't myLibrary.jar be able to locate the classes included in my job jar? Shall I make any specific configuration or this is not possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself. According to [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html) classes from user jars in a session cluster are loaded dynamically thus cannot be accessed by libs which are loaded in Flink's classpath. One solution is to put the user jars in the lib folder, which does not work for me as I want my users to be able to submit their jobs through the UI. Another solution that works for me is described in [this subsection](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#manual-classloading-in-user-code). Basically, when classes from users jars are needed, your Flink operators should instantiate a classloader by using the `getRuntimeContext().getUserCodeClassLoader()`. In order to do that, they should be Rich functions (e.g., RichFlatMapFunction). Then, using this classloader, you can call the `loadClass(className)` method pointing to the path where the user class is located.